# Pass in parameter in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I pass parameters for in attribute in C# to sqlserver.
I have to execute a stored procedure which expects parameters for in attribute.Please Let me Know how can I do that.....

Comment: Could you provide more information about the scenario? Right now it's hard to determine what ou are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to execute stored procedures is to use the SqlCommand object and the SqlParameter object.

You could build a collection of SqlParameter objects to represent your parameters and a function to run an SqlCommand to fill a DataSet, for example.

You could implement this with two functions, one a function that builds a list of SqlParameters which you call once for each parameter to add it to the list and one a function that takes that list and the name of the stored procedure etc and runs the stored procedure.

If you are only doing this one off these functions could be a bit of overhead so I've also shown an example doing it all in one function.

In my example below I've shown how to return a DataSet but you could use cmdt.ExecuteNonQuery() instead as in the standalone example.

---

A helper function to "build" a parameters list:

```
private void BuildSqlParameter(string ParameterName, SqlDbType DBType, 
    string Value, ParameterDirection dir, ref List<SqlParameter> paras)
{
     SqlParameter temp;
     temp = new SqlParameter(ParameterName, DBType);
     temp.Value = Value;
     temp.Direction = dir;
     paras.Add(temp);
}
```

A function to run the stored procedure:

```
private DataSet GetStoredProcedureWithParameters(SqlConnection SQLC, 
    string StoredProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> paras)
{
    SQLC.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdt = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, WEL);
    cmdt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdt.Parameters.AddRange(paras.ToArray());
    SqlDataAdapter dat = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdt);
    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    dat.Fill(dst);
    SQLC.Close();
    return dst;
}
```

And then call like this:
public SqlConnection MySQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=MyDB;SERVER=MyServer;Failover Partner=MyServer2;UID=MyID;PWD=MyPassword");
    List paras = new List();
    BuildSqlParameter("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 
        ParameterValue, ParameterDirection.Input, ref paras);
    DataSet local = GetStoredProcedureWithParameters(MySQLConnection, 
        "MyStoredProcedureName", paras);

Where:

- MySQLConnection is an SqlConnection (defined in this example for completeness)
- MyDB is the name of your database
- MyServer is the name of your server
- MyServer2 is the name of a failover server (not necessary)
- MyID is your SQL Server username
- MyPassword is your SQL Server password
- "@ParameterName" is the name of your parameter
- SqlDbType.VarChar is an example datatype for the second parameter
- ParameterValue is the variable you wish to pass to the parameter
- MyStoredProcedureName is the name of the stored procedure you want to run

If you need more than one parameter, just run BuildSqlParameter as many times as you need.

---

Or, if you just want some one off code do it like this:

```
MySQLConnection.Open();
SqlCommand cmdt = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedureName", 
    MySQLConnection);
cmdt.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter para = cmdt.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", 
    System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
para.Value = ParameterValue;
para.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmdt.ExecuteNonQuery();
MySQLConnection.Close();
```

To add more parameters this would be like:

```
SqlParameter para2 = cmdt.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName2", 
System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
para2.Value = ParameterValue2;
para2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Where:

- "@ParameterName2" is the name of your second parameter
- ParameterValue2 is the variable you wish to pass to the second parameter
- System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar is an example datatype for the second parameter

Comment: Sorry to have to downvote, but this doesn't answer the question, isn't entirely clear, and the code is not the best example of how to call an SP.

Comment: I disagree, the question is "execute a stored procedure which expects parameters" - that's what the code does. 
I'll add some more description of what it's doing.
If you disagree with how to call an SP could you provide a better example?

Comment: The code example you have provided gives a method name `ClearOrderToggle` which bears no meaning for the OP, a parameter `RepRef` which also has no meaning to us, a variable `MySQLConnection` which is not defined or explained, and also uses a loop to call `cmdt.Parameters.Add` multiple times, instead of calling `cmdt.Parameters.AddRange`, along with several other misleading/confusing examples.

Comment: Apologies - I had copied out of a set of code I had stored for my own reference - that method name was from an old project and shouldn't have been copied. I have added explanations for the variable names which I had hoped would be self explanatory but you are right to question. I was unaware of the AddRange option, so I have changed to this - thanks! I hope the example is clearer now but if you spot anything else I could improve please let me know.

Comment: @Jaymz I think PCurd indeed answers the question and I don't see any of your points being a reason to downvote. If you have a better answer post it because your comments add nothing beyond pollution.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, I agree it did provide _an_ answer to the question. It was, however, not a clear example, and did show several bad practices. Due to the additional explanations, and the new correctness of the code, I have changed my -1 to a +1. Nice answer.